# Is there jitsi SIP-client for Ubuntu or Debian which has command-line interface?

Tags: shell-script, shell, python, gnome-shell, python3

Is there jitsi SIP-client for Ubuntu or Debian which has command-line interface? So, for example, I can make calls without using jitsi GUI, just sending commands to the application.

Comment: It seems that there is no out-of-box commandline tool for jitsi SIP-client. If you get one, plz inform me. I am interested too.